# Get the day change point(s) between two UNIX timestamps

Tags: perl, timestamp

I have the date range (two UNIX timestamps) and I need to find point(s) at 23:59:59 if exists.
How I can do it with Perl?

P.S. I think for() is not good idea because I can have very big range. Anything another variants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `Date::Calc`.  Suppose your two timestamps are located in `$ts1` and `$ts2`:

```
use Date::Calc qw(Time_to_Date Date_to_Time Delta_Days Add_Delta_Days);

my @date1 = (Time_to_Date($ts1))[0..2];
my @date2 = (Time_to_Date($ts2))[0..2];
my @midnights;

for (my $i = 0; $i < Delta_Days(@date1, @date2); ++$i) {
    push @midnights, Date_to_Time(Add_Delta_Days(@date1, $i), 23, 59, 59);
}
```

`@midnights` now contains the UNIX timestamps (epoch seconds) of all 23:59:59 point(s) between the two given timestamps.

**Disclaimer**: Of course you could also do it with `DateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

That's a generic algorithm. X is the 1st timestamp Y is the last one

1) Get the first change date, Z.

```
If Z > Y , there is no change.
```

2) Get the last change date, W

```
   If W = Z, there is only one change date.
```

3) Get the range of dates, R. Considering the range of one day is D

```
   R = W - Z .. The number of points will be the integer of (W - Z)/D
```

Answer (score 1):

use [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime);

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example I scrapped together based on my semi-recent knowledge of the UNIX timestamp (school is such a long time ago...)

```
while (entry) {
   if ((timestamp-1) % 86400 == 0) {
      #match
   } else {
      #nomatch
   }
}
```

However, like everybody else, I would suggest using other tools to do that since my example does not take leap seconds into account and I highly doubt it's POSIX-compliant. More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).